Use QCheckbox to change data and view for a QStandardItemModel
I want to have a QChecbox that when checked it will make the model fetch some type of data and show it, and when is not to fetch some other kind of data.
The problem that I find is that I am not able to update the model view. I am printing the data and it seems to be fetching the correct data as I press the checkbox, but the view stays the same and I can not figure out why.
Here is my code:
This first bit is supposed to retrieve the data and it works, as the print(self._items) gives the right output.
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor, QFont
from PySide2.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
 
import smart_read
 
import sys
import collections
from collections import Counter
import nuke
 
 
class ShotModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ShotModel, self).__init__()
        self.rootItem = self.invisibleRootItem()
        self._items = {}
        #self.set_items()
        
    def set_items(self,elements_collapsed):
        shots_path = smart_read.find_current_job()
        self.elements_collapsed = elements_collapsed
 
        if self.elements_collapsed == False:
            print("False")
            all_elements = smart_read.Job(shots_path).find_JOB_elements()
            self._items = all_elements
            print(self._items)
            for shot,elements in sorted(self._items.items()):
                shot = QStandardItem(str(shot))
                self.rootItem.appendRow(shot)
 
                for element in elements:
                #print(element)
                    element = QStandardItem(str(element))
                    shot.appendRow(element)
            self.modelReset.emit()
 
        else:
            print("True")
 
            
            collapsed_elements = smart_read.Job(shots_path).find_JOB_elements()
            self._items = smart_read.collapse(collapsed_elements)
            print(self._items)
            for shot,elements in sorted(self._items.items()):
                shot = QStandardItem(str(shot))
                self.rootItem.appendRow(shot)
                for element in elements:
                    #print(element)
                    element = QStandardItem(str(element))
                    shot.appendRow(element)
            self.modelReset.emit()


On this second bit I create the Widget that contains my model.

class Panel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Panel, self).__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        self.treeModel = ShotModel()
        self.treeView.setHeaderHidden(True)
 
        self.version_checkbox = QCheckBox("show only latest version")
        self.version_checkbox.setChecked(True)
        self.version_checkbox.clicked.connect(self.show_latest_version)
        layout.addWidget(self.version_checkbox)
        layout.addWidget(self.treeView)
 
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.treeModel)
    

This function should then update the model data and view by calling the function above.
    def show_latest_version(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        if sender.isChecked():
            ShotModel().set_items(elements_collapsed=True)
            self.treeModel.modelReset.emit()
            self.treeView.setModel(self.treeModel)
        else:
            ShotModel().set_items(False)
            self.treeModel.modelReset.emit()
            self.treeView.setModel(self.treeModel)
 
 
panel = Panel()
panel.show()

So what I tried to do is to have a function (show_latest_version) that when the checkbox is chcked will be called. This should then update the dictionary from which the model takes the data from (self._items) and it actually does as when I am printing it the output is correct for both checked and unchecked.
But this doesn't make the  view change - the data seems to remain the same.

ShotModel() creates a completely new instance, so what you're doing there is completely useless: 1. it has absolutely no effect on the current model; 2. you're creating a new instance that is also instantly destroyed. You should call set_items() on the existing one, but what you do there is quite unclear (especially the modelReset.emit() which makes no sense) and probably unacceptable for multiple calla. Please provide a proper [mre] if you want more comprehensive help.

Thank you  @musicamante the problem was calling a new instance so the old one would just get destroyed. I have updated the code  without the new isntance and cleared out the modelReset.emit() - i thought I needed that but i didnt.

Almost all signals of Qt models should only be emitted from subclasses of abstract item models (QAbstractItemModel, etc.). Such signals also have a "begin" counterpart, so emitting modelReset alone would be wrong without a preceding modelAboutToBeReset. Fully implemented models such as QStandardItemModel already do all that on their own. In this case, if you want to clear the model and fill it with new items, then use the related clear() function (which, in fact, also does all the above), so you don't need replacing the model on the view.

This is the solution found, using the same instance that was used before instead of calling a new one:
    def show_latest_version(self):
    sender = self.sender()
    if sender.isChecked():
        self.treeModel.set_items(True)
    else:
        self.treeModel.set_items(False)


Note that: 1. the toggled is more appropriate for checkable buttons; 2. you don't need to get the sender, since toggled (and, actually, clicked too) already provides that as its argument. In fact, for cases in which the signal argument is compatible with the actual function to be called, you don't need to create a further function at all; just change the signal connection to self.version_checkbox.toggled.connect(self.treeModel.set_items), and you can get rid of show_latest_version completely.
